# Issues with installing/using a downloaded nuget package (in Xamarin-Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, nuget-package

I am coding on my mac (Xamarin-Studio) and my goal is to code a C# app for Android and IOS. Here's my issue.

I downloaded a nuget-package (ZXing.Net.Mobile) successfully (since i can see it in the package folder of the solution). Then i went to the solution.IOS to *AppDelegate* and wanted to apply this code `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();` (as told in the github readme file) but then it says

> /Users/summerdream/Projects/Secretary/iOS/AppDelegate.cs(13,13): Error
>   CS0103: The name 'ZXing' does not exist in the current context
>   (CS0103) (Secretary.iOS)

Ive been trying to get rid of this problem for 3 days now and i didnt get anywhere. Could anyone give me some tips?

Comment: is the package installed in your iOS project?

Comment: Well i have 3 projects (App, App.IOS, App.Droid). And I've installed it on the App

Comment: you need to install it in EACH project

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out Jason. I added the package to every Project and now its giving me again an error.             /Users/summerdream/Projects/Secretary/iOS/AppDelegate.cs(13,13): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'ZXing' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (Secretary.iOS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the **ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms** for your solution, not the **Zxing.Net.Mobile**.

1. Right click the **Solution**.
2. Click "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..."
3. Uninstall the **Zxing.Net.Mobile** package.
4. Search the **ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms** package and install it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your halp Kevin. I still have some issues on how to use this package and actually create a page (Scan-Page) where i can scan a qr code and then store the content in a variable for later use.

Comment: You may file a new question on other issues.

Comment: If this answer is helpful, could you please accept it?

Comment: Oh thanks for your advice. And sorry about me not accepting your answer. I wasnt aware of it. Ill do it straight away:)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the version 2.1.47

**ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.1.47**